# Is a kilonova bigger than a supernova?

Tags: supernova

My question is straight forward.  Is a [kilonova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilonova) bigger than a supernova?

**Update**

How does a kilonova differ from a nova in terms of...

- luminosity
- duration
- energy
- volume of space occupied by the ejecta
- speed of the ejecta
- other metrics?

Comment: How would you define "bigger"? More luminous? More energetic? Longer-lasting?

Comment: Thanks, HDE226868!  I think I get it.  Your comment, the answer PeterErwin provided, and the link uhoh provided have given me a picture of what kilonovas are like.  I refined the question for the sake of the site...  I left out supernovas and "hypernovas" (just learned about the latter today) though maybe that info could go here, too.  Or maybe this question is answered well enough already.

Comment: Kilonova sounds a lot like supermoon; mostly journalistic in nature. If you take it literally, it means a thousand times as much of *something*, in this case "nova".

Comment: Wayfaring Stranger -- That is the original intended meaning: roughly 1000 times as much energy as a (classical) nova.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although it's a little tricky to say what "bigger" means in this context, the answer is, in most senses, no.

A supernova puts out about ten to a hundred times as much energy in the form of light, and hundred or more times as much matter is ejected. (A core-collapse supernova undoubtedly puts out much more energy in the form of neutrinos as well.) What matter *is* ejected by a kilonova *does* go out faster (30-60,000 km/s, versus about 10,000 km/s for supernova ejecta).

On the other hand, a kilonova puts out much more energy in the form of gravitational waves, so they're bigger in that sense.