# How big would the supernova when a neutron star collides with another neutron star?

Tags: black-hole, supernova, neutron-star, deep-sky-observing, kilonova

If two neutrons stars that are orbiting were to collide, how big would the supernova explosion be?

Would a new black hole or a new supernova remnant be formed?

Comment: What is a "neutron supernova collision"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a kilonova bigger than a supernova?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/23184/is-a-kilonova-bigger-than-a-supernova)

Answer (score 2):

When two neutron stars collide, the resulting supernova is called a "kilonova," producing much more energy than a regular supernova. Additionally, heavier elements are formed, such as gold, platinum, etc. Other effects of this collision include a gamma-ray burst and/or gravitational waves. The object formed after the event can either be a heavier neutron star, or a black hole (if the mass of the merger exceeds the maximum mass of a neutron star, about 3 solar masses).

As of right now, we have not detected a neutron star merger that is visible to the naked eye; almost all of them occurred in different galaxies, billions of light-years away. I hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you say that a kilonova produces more energy than a supernova? The ejecta from a kilonova can have higher speeds than supernova ejecta, but the total energy released is generally much smaller. Please see the question linked above by antispinwards.